# Create object in java with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, for-loop

ok so lets say I got class Bulb and class Picture.
In bulb I got boolean variable if it is true the bulb is on if not the bulb is off I made it in the constructor that is off by default and made 2 method turnOn and turnOff.
I need to make in picture arrays of Bulbs the user enter (in the main method when he creates the object picture) the length of the array . 
so lets say this is my picture class :

```
private Bulb [] arr ;

Picture(int len)
{   
    Bulb [] arr = new Bulb[len];
}
```

Now if I want to enter bulb on each cell I need to do this :

```
Bulb b = new Bulb();
Bulb c = new Bulb();
Bulb d = new Bulb();

for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    arr[i] = b;
    arr[i] = c;
    arr[i] = d;
}
```

Of course I can't do this in that way I don't now how many object to create its by the variable len .

Comment: You're currently overwriting each assignment you do to `arr[i]`.

Comment: Why you need to use for loop?

Comment: Why not `for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) { arr[i] = new Bulb(); }` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `length` attribute of an array to fill an array with bulbs.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Bulb();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create all `Bulb` instances before the loop, because you simply don't know how many you need. Why don't you try something simple like the below?

```
private Bulb [] arr ;

Picture(int len)
{   
    arr = new Bulb[len];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new Bulb();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which is an resizable array implementation of the List.

> ...
> ArrayList<Bulb> bulbs = new ArrayList<Bulb>();
> for(Class cell:cells) {
>     bulbs.add(new Bulb());
> }
> ...

**-OR-**

If you really want number related indices to pull the bulb back later:

> ...
> HashMap<int,Bulb> bulbs = new HashMap<int,bulb>();
> for(int i=0,i<len;i++) {
>    bulbs.put(i,new Bulb);
> }
> ...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- Your constructor creates a new variable rather than instantiating the field
- Your for loop writes each bulb to the same index.  You will end up with an array of 'd' bulbs

It might be easier to use a List if you need to access your Bulbs by index, or a Set if you don't.

```
private List<Bulb> bulbs;

Picture(int len)
{   
    bulbs = new ArrayList<Bulb>()
}
```

and then

```
Bulb b = new Bulb();
Bulb c = new Bulb();
Bulb d = new Bulb();

bulbs.add(b);
bulbs.add(c);
bulbs.add(d);
```

Then, for example to get bulb B:

```
bulbs.get(1);
```